# Sending IMs through an API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, open-source, instant-messaging

we're looking at add a new feature to our site which would allow users who want to receive updates about their profile to get them sent directly to their **Instant Messaging** account (eg. Yahoo, Live Messenger, AIM, etc.).

We're currently in the preliminary stages, just gathering information and seeing if it's actually something we want to do, so I was wondering if anyone here might be able to help us discover if there's a good solution out there?

There's so many cross-network IM platforms (several leap to mind, [Trillian](http://www.trillian.im/), [X-Fire](http://www.xfire.com/cms/about_aim/), [Meebo](http://www.meebo.com/), [Miranda](http://www.miranda-im.org/), [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/), [Raptr](http://raptr.com/), [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/)) but I really don't know a good place to start with regards to using an API. Is there an open-source cross-platform IM API around?

Comment: A best way to do it would be using a SMS gateway like Twilio http://www.twilio.com/sms/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could possibly use [libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/), which is what Pidgin and Adium use. It is GPL'd though, so not sure if this would make it unsuitable, depending on what modifications, if any, you made to it.

Comment: Awesome information. That is precisely the type of thing I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol
[XMPP](http://xmpp.org/)

That's for Jabber/XMPP.

But the rest are all closed source projects with closed protocols.
The cross-network IMs are all using reengineered protocols like libpurple.

Answer (score 2):

[Libpurple](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple) is a core api that you can build your IM support on. It is used by several of the clients you mentioned, including several web applications.